# After new install of wampserver, MySQL service not starting

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I just installed wampserver on my machine and I cannot get it to start, the icon stays orange. I am using Windows7 Home Premium (64-bit) and I installed wampserver 2.2E (64-bit). I did not have any issues with the install. I checked port 80 and it's being used by Apache. So it seems like the apache service is running, but the MySQL service is not. I tried turning off the firewall, I checked if a different MySQL service was running, and I tried to start wampmysqld manually in Services. When I tried to start wampmysqld in Services, an error came up saying

> Windows could not start the wampmysqld service on Local Computer.
>   Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

And when I view the MySQL log, it says:

> 140216 21:52:04 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>   140216 21:52:04 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
>   140216 21:52:04 [ERROR] wampmysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'
>   140216 21:52:04 [ERROR] Aborting
>   140216 21:52:04 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown completeBlockquote

Answer (score 11):

1. Stop the MySQL service
2. Open data folder
3. Remove both `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`
4. Restart the service

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `my.ini` file. Use the wampmanager menus to open an editor on my.ini

```
left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> my.ini
```

Change the parameter

```
skip-locking
```

To

```
skip-external-locking
```

Its just an old parameter that they forgot to change when releasing this version of WAMP.